# Scikit-Learn giving incorrect R Squared value

Tags: python, python-3.x, scikit-learn, statistics

I'm training Machine Learning models on Python and using R squared metric from Scikit Learn to evaluate them. Id decided to play around with Scikit's r2_score function, feeding it a random array of same value as input y_true and and slightly different but same value array as y_predict. I was getting arbitrarily large (negative) values when the input length of array is 10 or more and 0 when the input length is less than 10.

```
from sklearn.metrics import r2_score
r2_score([213.91666667,  213.91666667,  213.91666667,  213.91666667,  213.91666667, 
      213.91666667, 213.91666667,  213.91666667,  213.91666667,  213.91666667],
    [213,  214,  214,  214,  214,  214,  214,  214,  214,  214])

>>> -1.1175847590636849e+26

r2_score([213.91666667,  213.91666667,  213.91666667,  213.91666667, 
      213.91666667, 213.91666667,  213.91666667,  213.91666667,  213.91666667],
    [213,  214,  214,  214,  214,  214,  214,  214,  214])

>>> 0
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're correct in noting that the `r2_score` output is not correct. However, this is a result of a simpler computation issue rather than a problem with the scikit-learn package.

Try running

```
>>> input_list = [213.91666667,  213.91666667,  213.91666667,  213.91666667,  213.91666667, 
  213.91666667, 213.91666667,  213.91666667,  213.91666667,  213.91666667]
>>> sum(input_list)/len(input_list)
```

As you can see, the output is not exactly 213.91666667 (a limited precision error; you can read more about it [here](http://floating-point-gui.de/basic/)). Why does this matter?

Well, the section of the scikit-learn [User Guide](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/model_evaluation.html#r2-score) gives the specific formula used to calculate `r2_score`:

[image: r2 formula]

As you can see, the `r2_score` is simply 1 - (residual sum of squares)/(total sum of squares).

In the first case you specify, the residual sum of squares is equal to some number that...doesn't really matter. You can calculate it easily; it's about 0.09, which doesn't seem super high. However, due to the floating point error described above, the *total sum of squares* isn't exactly 0, but rather some very, very small number (think around 10^-28 -- *very* small).

Thus, when you divide residual sum of squares (around 0.09) by total sum of squares (a very small number), you're left with a very large number. Since that large number is subtracted from 1, you are left with a negative number of high magnitude as your `r2_score` output.

This imprecision in the calculation of total sum of squares does not occur in the second case, so the denominator is 0 and the function, seeing an undefined value from of the calculations, should return 0.

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the [source code of r2_score](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/ab93d65/sklearn/metrics/regression.py#L370), we can see the following lines (default weights assigned)

```
weight = 1
sample_weight = None

y_true = np.array([213.91666667,  213.91666667,  213.91666667,  213.91666667,    213.91666667, 213.91666667, 213.91666667,  213.91666667,  213.91666667,  213.91666667]).reshape(-1,1)

y_pred = np.array([213,  214,  214,  214,  214,  214,  214,  214,  214,  214]).reshape(-1,1)

numerator = (weight * (y_true - y_pred) ** 2).sum(axis=0,
                                                  dtype=np.float64)
denominator = (weight * (y_true - np.average(
    y_true, axis=0, weights=sample_weight)) ** 2).sum(axis=0,
                                                      dtype=np.float64)
nonzero_denominator = denominator != 0
nonzero_numerator = numerator != 0
valid_score = nonzero_denominator & nonzero_numerator
output_scores = np.ones([y_true.shape[1]])
output_scores[valid_score] = 1 - (numerator[valid_score] /
                                  denominator[valid_score])

return np.average(output_scores, weights=None)
```

The problematic line in your case is the `denominator` calculation.

For the first case:

```
denominator = (weight * (y_true - np.average(
    y_true, axis=0, weights=sample_weight)) ** 2).sum(axis=0,
                                                      dtype=np.float64)

print(denominator)

[  8.07793567e-27]
```

Its pretty small, but not 0.

For second case: its 0.

Since the denominator is 0, the r2_score is undefined and returns 0. Hope I'm clear.

Answer (score 0):

This has not to do with scikit learn, but with the concept of R^2 itself.
Intuitively, you can think at it as the ratio of variance of Y explained by your explanatory variables X.

Here X variance is zero (you always repeat the same number), hence the R^2 being zero (when the two vectors have same length).

If the two vectors have different length...well the regression itself is not well defined. I guess it would be better if the function returned error.

Comment: Both the cases in the question have same length. Its the length of that array which the OP is noting about.